# Error while passing a value from view to controller method in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have tried the following code to pass the value from my_view.php(view) to myproject/delete (controller method) in codeigniter.

```
 $val=$my_records['roll_no']
```

up to here, there is no error and the roll no is stored in value and when i print that value, it is printed. But when I passed the $val to the method delete of controller class, it showed an error message

> "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.".

The portion of my code is:: `echo site_url('myproject/update/$val')`

there is a method update in my controller myproject.php and it takes `$roll_no` as argument.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double quotes for your parameter. Single quotes prevent the variable from being parsed as PHP considers the `$` to be a string literal.

```
<td><a href ="<?php echo site_url("myproject/update/$val ")?>">Edit</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url?>myproject/edit/<?php echo $my_records['roll_no']?>">Edit</a>
```

and your roll_no (and uri) regex must be:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

You can edit it in config/config.php.

*** I'm trying to learn English so i speak not well.